# Google Cloud Platform file to node server via gcloud

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, gcloud-node

I have a bucket on Google Cloud Platform where part of my application adds small text files with unique names (no extension).

A second app needs to retrieve individual text files (only one at a time) for insertion into a template.

I cannot find the correct api call for this.

Configuration is as required:

```
var gcloud = require('gcloud');

var gcs = gcloud.storage({
    projectId: settings.bucketName,
    keyFilename: settings.bucketKeyfile 
});
var textBucket = gcs.bucket(settings.bucketTitle);
```

Saving to the bucket works well:

```
textBucket.upload(fileLocation, function(err, file) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("File not uploaded: " + err);
    } else {
        // console.log("File uploaded: " + file);
    }
});
```

The following seems logical but returns only metadata and not the actual file for use in the callback;

```
textBucket.get(fileName, function(err, file) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("File not retrieved: " + err);
    } else {
        callback(file);
    }
});
```

Probably no surprise this doesn't work since it's not actually in the official documentation but then again, neither is a simple asnyc function which returns a document you ask for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `get` on a `Bucket` object is documented here: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.29.0/storage/bucket?method=get

If you want to simply download the file into memory, try the method `download` on a `File` object: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.29.0/storage/file?method=download. You can also use [`createReadStream`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.29.0/storage/file?method=createReadStream) if using a stream workflow.

If you have ideas for improving the docs, it would be great if you opened an issue on https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcloud-node so we can make it easier for the next person.

Comment: Steven, thanks for this - I actually just came back to write up my solution which is essentially what you put; calling download on a File object. Additionally, the files are JSON but came back with backslashes added - JSON.parse() was needed. Documentation is probably fine; I'm just not much of a programmer...